# How to copy the phone number of the sender of a text message in Android default messaging program?

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, sms

How to copy the phone number of the sender of a text message in Android default messaging program? Does one have to go through "create a new contact" through the `+` menu, or is there any faster way?

I use unrooted Android 6.0 on LG4.

I don't see any "people & options" in the menu:

[image]

Comment: I did not pay attention on the phone and Android version when I answered. I will delete my answer.

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio you're welcome to keep the answer, it's still very useful to know for more recent versions.

Answer (score 1):

> Does one have to go through "create a new contact" through the + menu, or is there any faster way?

You can copy the phone number without selecting "Create a new contact". I don't know if there is a faster way but here is how to do it:

1. On the default messaging app, open the text message (SMS) whose phone number you want to copy.
2. Click the 3-dot, then "People & options".
3. Long press the phone number. A message "Copy to clipboard?" will appear, click on "Copy".

Edit: The answer is probably more useful if using Android 7 and above. I deleted, then restored it based on the comments. If it is against the rules, moderators please take the appropriate action(s).

Comment: Thank you, I don't see any "people & options" in the menu: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uKcdO.jpg